# How can I get high accuracy location every 5 seconds or when user moves a threshold without draining the battery?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a location app that needs to get accurate location periodically.  Currently I am getting constantly getting location in `didUpdateLocation` but I only ever log the location every 5 seconds.  I am interested in a solution that gets accurate location periodically or on signification change.  I would like either or both of these scenarios:
(by very accurate, I need 10m of desired accuracy)

- Get a very accurate location every 5 seconds
- Notify/callback if user moves a threshold ( eg moves 5 - 10 meters)

The app needs to work when backgrounded as well and location must still be logged if user switches to another app.

I was considering turning on/off location every 5 seconds but was not sure if that is the best practice.   I also know there is also `allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled`  but I believe that only applied to backgrounded mode.  I would appreciate a solution that saves battery when the app is in use and in background mode.  Please share your solutions and best practices for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

I did write an app using Location services, app must send location every 10s. And it worked very well.

Just use the ["allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW54) method, following Apple's doc.

Steps are as follows:

Required: Register background mode for update Location.

1. Create LocationManger and startUpdatingLocation, with accuracy and filteredDistance as whatever you want:

   ```
   -(void) initLocationManager    
   {
    // Create the manager object
    self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
   // This is the most important property to set for the manager. It ultimately determines how the manager will
   // attempt to acquire location and thus, the amount of power that will be consumed.
   _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 45;
   _locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;
   // Once configured, the location manager must be "started".
   [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
   }
   ```
2. To keep app run forever using "allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout" method in background, you must restart updatingLocation with new parameter when app moves to background, like this:

   ```
   - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    _isBackgroundMode = YES;

    [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [_locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [_locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
     _locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
     _locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
   ```
3. App gets updatedLocations as normal with "locationManager:didUpdateLocations:" callback:

   ```
   -(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
   {
    //  store data
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
    self.userLocation = newLocation;

    //tell the centralManager that you want to deferred this updatedLocation
   if (_isBackgroundMode && !_deferringUpdates)
   {
   _deferringUpdates = YES;
   [self.locationManager allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:CLLocationDistanceMax timeout:10];
    }
   }
   ```
4. But you should handle the data in then "locationManager:didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError:" callback for your purpose

   ```
   - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError:(NSError *)error {

    _deferringUpdates = NO;

    //do something 
    }
   ```
5. NOTE: I think we should reset parameters of LocationManager each time app switches between background/forgeround mode.

Hopefully this should help

Comment: Wouldn't you also need to set _isBackgroundMode = NO somewhere such as applicationWillEnterForeground?

Comment: Sure change it according to your need